# GUI to include a .prop file in a VS 2010 project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 has no longer uses `.vsprops` files and instead uses `.props` files.

To include a `.vsprops` file in a Visual Studio 2008 project, one could right-click the project icon in the *Solution Explorer* panel, choose *Properties*, go to the *Configuration Properties | General* section, and modify the *Inherited Project Property Sheets* property to contain a list of `.vsprops` paths.  One could also modify the Visual Studio 2008 project file directly.

Is there a way in the Visual Studio 2010 GUI to include `.props` files in a project?  The *Inherited Project Property Sheets* property seems to have been removed.  If manual editing of the project file is the only way to include `.props` files, where can one find documentation on doing it?

I'm not talking about adding a `.props` file to the list of files in the project, I mean how do I tell the project to **use** a `.props` file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That hasn't changed.  Use View > Other Windows > Property Manager.  Navigate the tree view there and open the configuration you want to change.  Right-click > Add New.

---

If you don't see this menu option then you can repair the menu with Tools > Customize, Commands tab.  Select 
"View" and click Add Command.  Select "View" in the left listbox, "Property Manager" in the right one.  That adds the command back to your View menu.

It is odd that it is missing of course, could have happened when you installed VS2010 and it imported your VS2008 settings.  This feature is not flawless, judging from other programmers' questions about it, beware that you might be missing out on other menu items.  If you haven't customized anything extensively then Tools > Import and Export Settings, Reset might be a good idea.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but I see *View | Other Windows | Properties Window* (but nothing named *Property Manager*).  If this is what you meant, I still don't see any way to include a `.props` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to View -> Other Windows -> Property Manager to open up the list of property sheets and so on. This works in both VS 2008 & 2010.

Comment: OK, but where do I specify a `.props` file?  There is still no *Inherited Project Property Sheets* property visible.  Does VS hide this property by default?  Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: @jwfearn: you don't need to. The property manager shows the inheritence tree directly. Just add new property sheets under existing ones and use drag & drop to change the tree around as required.

Answer (score 2):

Once you find the Property Manager you will see a list of your projects. right click on the project that you want to add a .props file for and choose "Add Existing Property Sheet".  You can also choose to add a new property sheet.  I have my property sheet in the same folder as my solution file so that all my projects can use the same property sheet.

Answer (score 0):

These posts didn't quite answer my need to choose the right Boost downloaded binaries library folder. boost_1_61_0_b1 lib32-msvc-14.0 or lib64-msvc-14.0

For some suggestions for this application see

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/How-to-write-one-property-page-props-to-select-the-right-x86-or-x64-Boost-libraries-folder-automatico-td4686269.html#a4686272